# Codec2 implementation for Android

Tags: android, kotlin, codec

I'm looking for [Codec2](https://github.com/drowe67/codec2) impl for Android. Found [THIS](https://github.com/UstadMobile/Codec2-Android) library, looks promising

I've tried to implement encode-decode logic like below, but I'm getting very distorted, hardly understandable audio output. When I try to use [built-in decoder](https://github.com/UstadMobile/Codec2-Android/blob/master/libcodec2-android/src/main/java/com/ustadmobile/codec2/Codec2Decoder.java) then output is unrecognizable at all (but works with sample file from assets). What I'm missing?

```
companion object {
    public const val codec2mode = Codec2.CODEC2_MODE_3200

    private const val sampleRate = 8000 // enough
    private const val audioFormat = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT
    private const val monoStereoIn = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO
    private const val monoStereoOut = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO
}

private val minBufSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, monoStereoIn, audioFormat)

private val c2instance = Codec2.create(codec2mode)
private val bits = Codec2.getBitsSize(c2instance) // bytes?
private val samples = Codec2.getSamplesPerFrame(c2instance)

fun recordData(): CharArray {
    Timber.i("recordData bits:$bits, samples:$samples, minBufSize:$minBufSize")
    val recorder = getRecorder()

    val recorderBuffer = ShortArray(samples.coerceAtLeast(minBufSize))
    val framesNum = recorderBuffer.size / samples

    Timber.i("startRecording recorderBuffer size:${recorderBuffer.size} framesNum:$framesNum")
    recorder.startRecording()

    val start = System.currentTimeMillis()

    val encodedBuffer = CharArray(bits)
    var encodedBufferSum = CharArray(0)

    var it = 50
    while (it > 0) {
        recorder.read(recorderBuffer, 0, recorderBuffer.size)
        for (i in 0 until framesNum) {
            Codec2.encode(c2instance, recorderBuffer, encodedBuffer)
            encodedBufferSum += encodedBuffer
        }
        it--
    }

    Timber.i(
        "encode finished in " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) +
            "ms, data length:${encodedBufferSum.size}",
    )

    return encodedBufferSum
}

fun playData(encodedBuffer: CharArray) {
    Timber.i("playData bits:$bits, samples:$samples, minBufSize:$minBufSize")
    val start = System.currentTimeMillis()

    val audioTrack = getAudioTrack().apply { play() }

    var workingCopy = encodedBuffer.clone()
    var it = 0
    while (workingCopy.isNotEmpty()) {
        val frame = workingCopy.slice(0 until bits).toCharArray()

        var codec2Buffer = ByteArray(0)
        frame.forEach { codec2Buffer += it.code.toByte() }

        val playbackAudioBuffer = ShortArray(samples)
        Codec2.decode(c2instance, playbackAudioBuffer, codec2Buffer)

        audioTrack.write(playbackAudioBuffer, 0, playbackAudioBuffer.size)

        workingCopy = workingCopy.slice(bits until workingCopy.size).toCharArray()

        it++
    }

    Timber.i(
        "decode and play finished in " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) +
            "ms, iterations:$it",
    )
}
```

output log:

```
  recordData bits:8, samples:160, minBufSize:640
  startRecording recorderBuffer size:640 framesNum:4
  encode finished in 4138ms, data length:1600
  playData bits:8, samples:160, minBufSize:640
  decode and play finished in 3999ms, iterations:200
```

btw. I've found [THIS](https://github.com/sh123/codec2_talkie) project implementing above lib, probably works, but I don't have devices to try out... and [HERE](https://devserver3.ustadmobile.com/repo-mvn/com/ustadmobile/codec2/libcodec2-android/) we have already built AARs (personally using `0.8-SNAPSHOT64-2`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answer current for version [`1.2.0`](https://github.com/drowe67/codec2/releases/tag/1.2.0)

bug is burried on JNI side in [`encode`](https://github.com/UstadMobile/Codec2-Android/blob/master/libcodec2-android/src/main/cpp/Codec2JNI.cpp#L59) method, in there happens some unnecessary dividing/downsampling. instead of

```
short v = (short) jbuf[i * 2];
```

should be

```
short v = (short) jbuf[i];
```

for current version there is a simple workaround - just add some extra dummy bytes (every second/even position), which are going to be ommited by buggy `for` loop

```
val frameBuffer: ShortArray = ... e.g. from AudioRecorder
var bugAround = ShortArray(0)
frameBuffer.forEach {
    bugAround += it // one short  single sample
    bugAround += 0x00
}
// bugAround now have 2x size as frameBuffer
Codec2.encode(c2instance, bugAround/*frameBuffer */, encodedBuffer)
```

more desription and workaround in [issue on github](https://github.com/UstadMobile/Codec2-Android/issues/1)

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately it has been a while since I worked on this one actively. I have answered the [issue posted on GitHub](https://github.com/UstadMobile/Codec2-Android/issues/1) as best I can from what I can remember: I think the sample files had headers that were the same size (or multiples thereof) the frame size. When the frame size changed and this wasn't the case, it resulted in the data frames being out of alignment.

Unfortunately I don't have the time to resolve this at the moment. I can provide hints/advice via the Github issue and I am happy to review/merge a pull request that fixes it.